# Measure the assortativity of a list of networks in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to measure the assortativity of a list of networks. This is how I generated the list.

```
nodes <- data.frame("Nodes" = 1:22,
                    "Type" = c(rep(1, 18), rep(0, 4)) # for measuring assortativity

set.seed(1)
nwl <- list()
for (x in seq_len(1000L)) {
    Start = 22, 500, replace=TRUE)
    End   = 22, 500, replace=TRUE)
    df = data.frame(Start, End)
    nwl[[x]]= graph_from_data_frame(df, 
                                    vertices = nodes,
                                    directed=TRUE)
}
```

I would like to apply something like this `assortativity(network, V(network)$Type, directed =T)` in the `sapply()` function for my list.

I have tried `sapply(nwl, V(nwl)$Type, directed =T)` , `sapply(nwl, sapply(nwl, V)$Type, directed = T)` , and `sapply(nwl, sapply(nwl, V, $Type), directed = T)` .

If there's a better way to do this without `sapply` I'll be thankful for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you'd like to loop through the list of networks `nwl` and apply the `assortativity`-function. In base R this can be achieved as follows:

`sapply(nwl, function(network) assortativity(network, V(network)$Type, directed =T))`

Here, I pass an anonymous function to `sapply` that builds around `assortativity`. A more intuitive way, and closer to your approach, this to use `map` from the `purrr` package:

`purrr::map_dbl(nwl, ~ assortativity(.x, V(.x)$Type, directed = T))`

It allows you to directly insert `.x` as placeholder for the network (specified in the argument `nwl`). I would not know how this could be done using base R.

The result should be equivalent regardless.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using the `purrr` package solution you provided.